# A more efficient way to sort the result of netstat command

Tags: command-line, text-processing, netstat

I was trying to sort only the IP addresses not related to firefox and write them in a file. I ended up with this command line, did the job but I am wondering if there is a way to do better.

```
netstat -antp | grep -E ?:80 | grep -v firefox > ipadress.txt &&  awk '{print $5}' ipadress.txt > ipadress1.txt
```

And is there a way to have a cleaner output by removing the :80 port?
I used the `ipadress1.txt` because when i tried to overwrite it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `awk` do all the work:

```
$ netstat -antp | awk '/:80/ && !/\/firefox/{print $5}'                                                           
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
151.101.129.69:80
67.132.183.24:80
91.189.89.144:80
151.101.129.69:80
:::*
```

#### Explanation

Typical `awk` program is structured this way:

```
/pattern/ {code to run if pattern matched}
```

In this particular case we use two patterns: we look for `:80` string and lines that don't have `/firefox` in them. The `&&` is logical AND, which means match *both* patterns on left and on right. If we have a match for such line - execute the codeblock, which prints only 5th field.